# Pandas - Get value as frequency in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Can someone help me with the (possible) groupby in pandas.

Here is the df:

```
    easy_donor  v_fam   count
0   donor_1_NS  IGHV1   5202376
1   donor_1_NS  IGHV2   1955547
2   donor_1_NS  IGHV3   70426272
3   donor_1_NS  IGHV4   452367
4   donor_1_NS  IGHV5   4842145
5   donor_1_NS  IGHV6   490142
6   donor_1_NS  IGHV7   19708
24  donor_2_NS  IGHV1   31258603
25  donor_2_NS  IGHV2   5295899
26  donor_2_NS  IGHV3   47286417
27  donor_2_NS  IGHV4   44553802
```

Then I want each count as a frequency of the sum of the counts grouped by donor.

Like:

```
df.groupby('easy_donor').sum()['count']
easy_donor
donor_1_NS     83394639
donor_2_NS    129191591
donor_3_HS    220549762
donor_3_NS    104821016
donor_4_HS    200444923
donor_4_NS    121287306
```

Then each count in the original data frame divided by the groupby sum if they match the easy_donor column. Do I have to join on original dataframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby('easy_donor')["count"].apply(lambda x: x / x.sum())
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, what you get is a pd.Series object, could you help me to get the original DataFrame format just with 'count' column substituted with the frequencies?

Answer (score 2):

FORGET THIS ANSWER!!! THIS IS JUST AN IDEA. NOT VIABLE

Note that using `pandas apply` is unbearably slow. Instead, try using the native **broadcasting**.

```
df.groupby(by='easy_donor')['count'] * 1. / df.groupby(by='easy_donor').sum()
```

Comment: This code raises this for me: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'SeriesGroupBy' and 'float'

Comment: @Mindcraft, I bet you forgot the `['count']` part.

Comment: Nope, I'm using exactly that line. A more minimum example:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'easy_donor':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'count':[123, 50, 30, 10, 20]})
df.groupby(by='easy_donor')['count'] * 1. / df.groupby(by='easy_donor').sum()`

Comment: @Mindcraft, yes, you are right, I finally see this is a stupid answer, and I should test it before posting it.